Flutter - open popup - check html on body
I have this problem 
I create app in Flutter and I am connected with my database (supabase). In my body table I have html text. Something like this: 
<p>This is an example article. <span class="highlight"  data-gallery-id="19">Click here</span> to see the gallery.</p>

Now I want to shop popup on my flutter screen when user click on Click here
My code - detail screen:


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;

class ArticleDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int articleId;

  ArticleDetailScreen({required this.articleId});

  final SupabaseClient supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchArticleDetails() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await supabase.from('articles').select().eq('id', articleId).single();

      return response as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching article details: $error');
      return {};
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchGalleryDetails(int galleryId) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabase
          .from('galleries')
          .select()
          .eq('id', galleryId)
          .single();

      return response as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching gallery details: $error');
      return {};
    }
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchGalleryImages(int galleryId) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabase
          .from('articles_images')
          .select()
          .eq('gallery_id', galleryId);

      return response as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching gallery images: $error');
      return [];
    }
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchSketchImages(int galleryId) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabase
          .from('sketches_images')
          .select()
          .eq('gallery_id', galleryId);

      return response as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching sketch images: $error');
      return [];
    }
  }

  void showGalleryPopup(BuildContext context, int galleryId) async {
    final galleryDetails = await fetchGalleryDetails(galleryId);
    final galleryImages = await fetchGalleryImages(galleryId);
    final sketchImages = await fetchSketchImages(galleryId);

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(galleryDetails['name'] ?? 'Gallery'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                if (galleryImages.isNotEmpty) ...[
                  Text('Zdjęcia'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      children: galleryImages.map((image) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Image.network(image['image_url'],
                              width: 100, height: 100),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                if (sketchImages.isNotEmpty) ...[
                  Text('Szkice'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      children: sketchImages.map((image) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Image.network(image['image_url'],
                              width: 100, height: 100),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Article Details'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        future: fetchArticleDetails(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('Article not found.'));
          } else {
            final article = snapshot.data!;
            final document = parse(article['body']);
            document
                .querySelectorAll('span[data-gallery-id]')
                .forEach((element) {
              final galleryId =
                  int.tryParse(element.attributes['data-gallery-id'] ?? '');
              if (galleryId != null) {
                element.attributes['onclick'] = 'flutter_gesture_detector';
                element.classes.add('highlight');
              }
            });

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Html(
                  data: document.outerHtml,
                  style: {
                    ".highlight": Style(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      textDecoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap:
                      (String? url, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
                    if (attributes['onclick'] == 'flutter_gesture_detector') {
                      final galleryId =
                          int.tryParse(attributes['data-gallery-id']!);
                      if (galleryId != null) {
                        showGalleryPopup(context, galleryId);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



When I click on Click here noting happen.
I dont know what to change or maybe you have another idea how to do it ?

